# Don't know how to send Integer value through Unity 3D using InputField

Tags: input, unity-game-engine, integer, textfield

For the most part, my code work.  What I want the code to do is have the input value be put into the pressureScript.  Right now, I have it set on 5, but I the number 5 to be replace with user input and not be define by the number 5 value.

When I submit, only the number 5 is being sent, not by the user input.

I also having issue with it being a string, but I wanted it to be an integer.  Any suggestions?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UserInput : MonoBehaviour {

    InputField input;

    public DataManager data;

        void Start ()

        {
            var input = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
            var se= new InputField.SubmitEvent();
            se.AddListener(SubmitName);
            input.onEndEdit = se;
        }


    private void SubmitName(string pressure)

        {

        var pressureScript = GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(DataManager)) as DataManager;
        pressureScript.pressure = 5;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Why did you ask the question twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the string using *int.TryParse(pressure, out intPressure)*

See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

For exemple :

```
int intPressure = 0;
if(int.TryParse(pressure, out intPressure))
{
    // Parse success, set the value of pressure in your component.
    pressureScript.pressure = intPressure;
}
else
{
    // Parse fail, show an error or something
}
```

Comment: You're answering everything here Sharundaar  :)

Comment: Got some time to spare in these day and age :)